# how to define a variable in laravel blade

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

How can define a variable in the view side(blade) in laravel?
I found that I can do it in this way:

```php
<?php $var = 'something' ?>
```

But is there any way to do this like `{{ $var = 'something' }}` or `@var1 = 'something'` ?(ofcourse  without printing it)

Comment: In this case you're just using Blade in a different way than it was designed for... You shouldn't put your data logic here... Just representation logic of already processed data...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I agree with @Kiril Ivanov answer, but if you still want to do that you can use

```
@php ($variable = 'test')
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful

Answer (score 2):

no, there is no way to define a variable with blade syntax except using the php syntax you have pointed. actually it is not a good practice to define variables in your views and do complex stuff except loops and conditional statements

Answer (score -3):

yes there is a way to do this

first assign your variable like this

```
{{ $yourvariable='' }}
```

and after than u can manipulate the variable

```
@if ($abc['type']=='youresult')
          {{ $yourvariable='success'}}

@endif
```

Hpe this works